# How to copy listview data to other form's listview c#

Tags: c#, forms, listview

I'm a newbie in c# so could you please me to fix my problem.I have two forms; `Form1` and `Form2`.Form1 include `Listview1` and Form2 include `listviewnew`.In Form1 I add some values on listview1 and I have a button name `Prew`. I know how to copy one listview to other listview at the same Form like the code below but I want to do ; When I click the `Prew` button copy listview1(FORM1) to listviewnew(FORM2).

```
private void prew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<ListViewItem> myList = new List<ListViewItem>();

            foreach (ListViewItem lvi in this.listView1.Items)
            {
                myList.Add(lvi);
            }

            this.listView1.Items.Clear(); // cut and paste it at the end of 2nd foreach iteration.

            foreach (ListViewItem lvi in myList)
            {
                this.listView2.Items.Add(lvi);
            } 
        }
```

Comment: Have Form1 and Form2 got connection in some way?

Comment: Yes when I click prew button it opens Form2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand,

You have to copy listview items in Form1 to listview in Form2

Here you can do this in simple way

Your `Form1.cs` look like

[image]

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add("ABC");
        listView1.Items.Add("PQR");
        listView1.Items.Add("XYZ");
    }

    private void btn_prew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2(listView1);
        frm2.Show();

    }
}
```

And `Form2.cs`

[image]

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public ListView _listView { get; set; }

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Form2(ListView listView)
        {
            _listView = listView;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listView1.Items.AddRange((from ListViewItem item in _listView.Items
                                      select (ListViewItem)item.Clone()).ToArray());
        }
    }
```

You just pass your listview in `Form1.cs` to `Form2.cs` with

`public ListView _listView { get; set; }` property.

Try once may it help you.

You simply not copy your listview items from one to other. So you have to `Clone()` your first listview items from Form1 to listview items to Form2.